# Regarding separable points of a a geometrically reduced integral affine scheme of finite type over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that if $X$ is a geometrically reduced integral affine scheme of finite type over $k$ (not necessarily algebraically closed), then the set of points of $X$ for which the residue field $\kappa(x)$ is a separable extension of $k$ is nonempty. (This are the so-called 'separable points' of $X$)

I have no idea how to proceed. I have found something close to it in Milne's notes on Algebraic geometry, but I can't make anything out of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Geometrically reduced precisely means that the generic point of $X$ is separable.

Comment: @Mohan: For me, goemetrically reduced means reduced after base change to the algebraic closure of the base field. How does that imply that theh generic point is separable? Can you please elaborate, or give some reference to this fact?

Comment: If $K\subset L$ is not a separable extension of fields, then $L\otimes_K \overline{K}$ is not reduced.

Comment: @Mohan In fact, I don't think your statement is always true. Separable points are always closed points (follows easily), but generic point may not be a closed point. Are you confusing between the function field being separable and separably generated over $k$? Or am I making some mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Mohan has given a big hint towards the answer in comments.

Related to Mohan's comment: note that geometrically reduced (for a finite type $k$ scheme) implies the existence of a smooth dense open subset, and a
smooth $k$-scheme always has a dense set of separable points (e.g. because the theory of etale local coordinates shows that it is covered by open subschemes each of which admits an etale map to an affine space).

[Recall that over an algebraically closed field, or more generally over a perfect field the smooth locus in a variety is always dense (if you look in the proof of 
this result in *Hartshorne*, you'll see the necessity of extracting $p$th
roots of certain coefficients in the positive char. case), but this need not hold over a non-perfect field.]

Indeed, one way to give a complete proof of the statement is to use that the smooth locus is open, and then to use Mohan's comment to show that it contains the generic point, and so is non-empty, thus dense.   (And now invoke the above result about separable points in smooth $k$-schemes.)

Comment: can you please give some reference to these?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of the proof. Let $X$ be integral and geometrically reduced over $k$. Then there exists a transcendence basis $t_{1},\ldots,t_{d}$ for $k(X)$ over $k$ such that $k(X)$ is separable over $k(t_{1},\ldots,t_{d})$ (such a basis is called a separating transcendence basis, and $k(X)$ is said to be separably generated over $k$). This means that $X$ is birationally equivalent to a hypersurface $f(T_{1},\ldots,T_{d+1})$, $d=\dim X$, such that $\partial f/\partial T_{d+1}\neq0$. It follows that the points $x$ in $X$ such that $\kappa(x)$ is separable over $k$ form a dense subset of $\left\vert X\right\vert $. In particular, $X(k)$ is dense in $\left\vert X\right\vert $
when $k$ is separably closed.